# ignore coverage bin of one instance of covergroup

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

How to ignore coverage bin for particular instance;
how to ignore bins one for cov2 instance ?

```
class cov extends uvm_subscriber # (transfer)
  function new(string name, uvm_component parent);
    super.new(name,parent);
    cov_tr = new();
    cov_tr.set_inst_name();
  endfunction

  function void write(transfer t);
    ignore_one = t.ignore_one;
    cov_tr.sample();
  endfunction

  covergroup cov_tr;
  option.per_instance = 1;
  tr_value : coverpoint tr_val {
    bins one : 1;
    bins next : [2:7];
  }
endgroup

cov cov1,cov2;
master1.connect(cov1.analysis_port);
master2.connect(cov2.analysis_port);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stop` method to stop collection of coverage, in a procedural block.

```
cov2.cov_tr.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Binning must be exactly the same for any instance of a given covergroup.